# Help me identify a 90s/00s live action tv show, space travel, golden object, maybe a saturday morning show?

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember watching a show a few times during the late 90s or early 00s, that involved a male teenage protagonist finding some kind of golden powerful object, and having to flee quickly, maybe into a spaceship? I can't remember very many specifics, but I remember the golden object thing may have been a weapon, or a source of knowledge, and could be carried with one hand. It also talked to our protagonist, either vocally or telepathically. I remember it telling him to run and there was something important for him to do as soon as he picked it up. It may have been found in some kind of pyramid, temple, or crashed spaceship that was similarly shaped.

From what I recall, there weren't many episodes, if any beyond a pilot, but it bugs me to this day I can't remember what it was. I know it wasn't Galador, as I have very clear memories of watching that show, and they are completely separate in my mind. If it helps, I remember a Z name, but I don't know if it was the title, a character, or what. It wasn't zathura, I've seen it again recently and it wasn't that.

Please, someone else has to know what I'm talking about! I know indidnt imagine it. Let's figure this out.

Comment: Could it possibly be Might Max? There is a villain named Zygote, and the cap is source knowldge/power...

Comment: @Durakken The show I remember was live-action. It was definitely not Mighty Max. Thank you though!

Answer (score 4):

It's possible that you are talking about the made-for-TV movie series of "Jack Kirby ... Time Warrior".  In the first film titled "Jack Kirby ... Time Warrior: Chapter 1, Planet of the Dino-Knights" there is:

1. A golden object found by a teenage boy which is a piece of a weapon
2. The protagonist fleeing using a ship
3. A central character named Zoetrope.

I can't remember if there was much telepathy emanating from the device.  The entire series is on YouTube if you want to check.